# Regex assistance: include/exclude

Tags: regex

Hello I am trying to figure out this RegEx expression.  I have a URL that can have different querystring parameter at different location.

```
test.aspx?foo=bar&abc=123
test.aspx?abc=123&foo=bar
test.aspx?foo=bar&abc=123#T1
test.aspx?abc=123&foo=bar#T2
```

I am trying to only find the one without the `#Tnumber`

Here what I have so far.

```
test.aspx\?(?!\#T[0-9])
```

However it still select all of them, is there a way to have a string constant and scan it down the line?

Juniorflip

Comment: Which language? Please add to tags...

Comment: why are you using regex for this? do you have no access to url parsing library?

Comment: I am using CrazyEgg Regex selector

Answer (score 0):

If `#Tnum` is always at the end, you just need to do a bit of anchoring. For example, like this:

```
test.aspx\?.*(?!\#T[0-9])...$
```

But that's very fragile as it depends on the bad URLs always ending in a very particular form and good URLs always having enough characters to soak up that end matching. A negative lookbehind assertion is somewhat better, but still fragile and less commonly supported:

```
test.aspx\?.*(?<!\#T[0-9])$
```

It's better to write a regular expression that matches what you *don't* want and to just invert the logic of what to do when you get a match (i.e., "if it matches throw it away", instead of "if it matches use it"). But really it's much better to delegate the parsing of the URLs to a specialized library and then just do a simpler check against the fragment identifier as a logical component instead of as a horrible RE hack.

Comment: why are you escaping hash sign?

Comment: Well I am trying to track the URL test.aspx but I want to remove the #Tnumber.  some of the Query string parameter could have a T in it

Comment: @Silent: Because it does no harm and it was done in the original.